# R: finding specific numbers of characters in a character array

Tags: r, regex

I want to find states with exactly two Os in the name. I tried this:

```
> data(state)
> index=grep('o.*o',state.name)
> state.name[index]
"Colorado"       "North Carolina" "North Dakota"   "South Carolina" "South Dakota"
```

Problem: there are three Os in "Colorado" and I don't want it. How can I revise my regex?

I also want to do three Os:

```
> data(state)  
> index=grep('o.*o.*o',state.name)  
> state.name[index]
"Colorado"
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ensure that the other characters that you're matching, besides the two matching Os, are not Os:

```
grep("^[^o]*o[^o]*o[^o]*$", state.name, value = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
grep('^([^o]*o[^o]*){2}$', state.name, value = TRUE)
# [1] "North Carolina" "North Dakota"
# [3] "South Carolina" "South Dakota"

grep('^([^o]*o[^o]*){3}$', state.name, value = TRUE)
# [1] "Colorado"
```

and as GSee suggested below, you can add `ignore.case = TRUE` if you want to include states with a capital O like Ohio, Oklahoma, and Oregon.

Comment: I always forget about `value = TRUE`.  +1

Comment: +1. As @user1547166 pointed out, the OP may want to include states that begin with a capital "O", in which case you could use `ignore.case=TRUE` in the `grep` call.

Comment: I like that this is easily generalizable to any number of Os. +1

Answer (score 2):

Michael's response is definitely more eloquent but here's the brute force method:

```
state.name[sapply(strsplit(tolower(state.name), NULL), function(x) sum(x %in% "o") == 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using ?gregexpr: A little ugly, but generalizes to other regexs well. (Don't forget the capital O in Ohio.)

```
state.name[sapply(state.name,function(x) length(unlist(gregexpr("o|O",x)))) == 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Count number of os in state name.

```
State <- c("North Dakota","Ohio","Colorado","South Dakota")
nos <- nchar(gsub("[^oO]","",State))
State[nos==2]
State[nos==3]
```